# Copy records from one table to another with pl-sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to copy records from one table to another. 
The only records from table 1 that will be copied to table 2 are the ones that still dont exist in table 2. 
If duplicate records exists in Table 1 then only be copied to table 2 the record with the larger size name.

I could already implement a query that almost does what I want.
The problem I have is when there are names with the same maximum size of characters.
In these cases, my query returns more than one record and I just want to insert one new record in table 2.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is my code:

```
For x in (Select distinct xdd.id_t, xdd.name_t
           From table1 xdd
          Where xdd.id_t not in (Select distinct det.id_t2
                                  From table2 det) 
            And LENGTH(xdd.name_t) in (Select Max(LENGTH(xdd2.name_t))
                                        From table1 xdd2
                                       Where xdd2.id_t = xdd.id_t) 
         ) Loop

    Insert into id_t2 (id_t2, name_t2)
       Values (x.id_t, x.name_t);         

End loop;
```

Comment: Based on information you've provided, you do not need to implement this kind of logic in PL/SQL using cursor `for` loop - use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF55127) statement. P.S. It would also be helpful if you provided sample of data and desired output.

Comment: With merge statement is possible to resolve the issue "when there are names with the same maximum size of characters"? Can you give me an example to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`Can you give me an example to solve this?`
Sure. If I understood requirements correctly, then the `merge` statement will look similar to this one:

We use `row_number()` analytic function to choose a duplicate record with longer `name_t`

```
merge into table_two t2
  using(
        select id_t
             , name_t
          from (select id_t
                     , name_t   
                     , row_number() over(partition by id_t 
                                             order by length(name_t) desc) as rn
                  from table_one) q
                 where q.rn = 1
         ) t1
     on (t2.id_t = t1.id_t)
when not matched then
   insert(id_t, name_t) 
     values(t1.id_t, t1.name_t)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c97c4/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is a merge statement that should "upsert" data from table 1 into table 2. Matching keys should update only when the name field in table1 is greater than that of table 2. And inserts should occur when keys from table one are not matched to table 2.

```
MERGE INTO table2 D
   USING (SELECT table1.id_t, table1.name_t FROM table1) S
   ON (D.id_t2 = S.id_t)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.name_t2 = S.name_t
     WHERE (LENGTH(S.name_t) > LENGTH(D.name_t2))
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.id_t, D.name_t)
     VALUES (S.id_t2, S.name_t2);
```